# CRR model arbitrage free

Tags: models

I'm currently studying [this proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiBNv.png)

In this proof the author defines a probability measure

$$P^*[\{\omega\}]=(p^*)^{k(\omega)}(1-p^*)^{T-k(\omega)}$$
on 
$$\Omega=\{\omega=(y_1,\ldots,y_T)|y_i=\pm1\}$$

where $p^*=(r-a)/(b-a)$ and $k(\omega)$ is the number of ones in $\omega$.

$a<r<b$.

Unfortunately I can't prove that $P^*$ is indeed a probability measure.

$P^*[\{\omega\}]\ge0$ is clear.

I don't see $P^*(\Omega)=1$

$P^*(\Omega)=\sum_{\omega_i \in \Omega}(p^*)^{k(\omega_i)}(1-p^*)^{T-k(\omega_i)}$, but I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $\omega$ and $\tilde{\omega}$ with $k(\omega)=k(\tilde{\omega})$ it holds that $P^*(\omega)=P^*(\tilde{\omega})$. Now instead of summing up over every $\omega_i \in \Omega$ you can sum up from $n =0 ... T$ and count the elements with $k(\omega_i)= n$. There are $\dbinom{T}{n}$ elements in $\Omega$ which fullfill $k(\omega_i)= n$.

Therefore $P^*(\Omega)=\sum_{\omega_i \in \Omega}(p^*)^{k(\omega_i)}(1-p^*)^{T-k(\omega_i)} = \sum_{n=0}^T \dbinom{T}{n} (p^*)^n(1-p^*)^{T-n}=1$ as a result from the binomial theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a clever way. How would you show additivity?